# why the svn branches are not cloned?

Tags: git, google-chrome, version-control, git-svn, git-branch

there are lots of branches on svn repo:

```
svn ls http://src.chromium.org/svn/
PRESUBMIT.py
branches/
codereview.settings
releases/
trunk/
```

after i cloned it using git svn clone, **there is no svn branches on my git svn repo, why?**

```
git svn clone -s --revision=157076   http://src.chromium.org/svn/
mirror0@lab:~/chrome/g/chrome_g$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/trunk
mirror0@lab:~/chrome/g/chrome_g$ git branch -r
  trunk
```

Answer (score 1):

git svn has some [commandline options](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html) which control how the svn-layout looks like. See the blog-post at http://www.jukie.net/bart/blog/svn-branches-in-git for more information about handling branches, specifically there are options to specify where trunk, branches and tags are, i.e. "-T trunk -b branches -t tags".

In your case it seems branches were created at the root folder directly, not sure if git svn supports this non-standard usage of branches...

Comment: -s option is used, so branches from svn repo should be cloned to git repo, but the fact is the same as this... -s means -T trunk -t tags -b branches, seems you don't know that...